# How can I create a generic type where T also can be int32,but not only a class

Tags: c#, class, generics, reference, int

I want to create a generic stack

I have a Node class

```
 public class GenericNode<T> where T : class
 {
    public T item;
    public GenericNode<T> next;

    public GenericNode()
    { 
    }
    public GenericNode(T item)
    {
        this.item = item;
    }
  }
```

And can use it like

```
GenericNode<string> node = new GenericNode<string>("one")
```

But I can't use it **also** like

```
GenericNode<int> node = new GenericNode<int>(1)
```

because int is not a reference type (not a class) and I use where T: class
But List is also not a reference type.

How can I fix my problem?

Comment: Line 4 is an infinite loop. --edit: Nevermind. Wrong language >.>

Comment: @Magtheridon96 How so?  It looks fine to me.  It's perfectly appropriate for a class to have a reference to another instance of that same type.  That's a perfectly valid implementation of a linked list.

Comment: @Servy Oh my, I retrieved this question while searching with the [c++] tag >.<. My bad then. Nevermind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the `struct` constraint (or `class` depending on which version of the question you look at) means that the type for `T` cannot be nullable and will throw an exception when you try to use `<string>`.

Removing it will allow you to do the steps you want.

```
public class GenericNode<T> where T : IConvertible
{
 public T item;
 public GenericNode<T> next;

 public GenericNode()
 { 
 }
 public GenericNode(T item)
 {
    this.item = item;
 }
}

void Main()
{
 GenericNode<string> node = new GenericNode<string>("one");
 GenericNode<int> node2 = new GenericNode<int>(1);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Don't use either `struct` or `class` as a generic constraint.  You can then use either.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake and late night... Your answer was ok!

Answer (score 6):

Remove the `class` constraint:

```
public class GenericNode<T> /* where T : class*/
```

If you leave off that constraint, it will allow your class to work with any type, whether it's a value or reference type.